# How to reference an AppController public function in a Plugins AppController in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp

Something that should be trivial in IMHO.

I have a public function in my webapp `AppController` - call it `getDbConfig()`

I have a plugin  and I want to reference the getDbConfig() function that was defined in the system-wide AppController.

Obviously   `$this->getDbConfig()`   does not work - since $this refers to the local context - but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to specify the path to public functions in the system `AppController` in Plugin `AppControllers`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make sense IMHO. A plugin is made to live outside you application. Ideally you could make you plugin public so that other developers could use it inside their application.

If you reference a function that you (and only you) have in your AppControll your plugin is no more a plugin.

I think that this is the typical case where you should create a Component. Put the `getDbConfig()` inside a Component so that you can call that component both from the Plugin and the AppController

Answer (score 1):

> but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to specify the path to public functions in the system AppController in Plugin AppControllers

Read about [php OOP namespace basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php). You need to import and alias the class. And inherit from your apps AppController. This would make the plugin rely on having the `App` namespace available, however, at least I have never seen a CakePHP app using another namespace. If it's another one the developer can still fork and use that fork and make the change to it.

Alternatively make the code in question a component or utility class and check in your plugins AppController if that class exists and then instantiate the utility lib it or load the component.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the function to your plugin/component as a configuration parameter, or the results from getDbConfig() (I assume it won't change much).

So:

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
  private $dbconfig = null;

  public function initialize (array $config)
  {
     parent::initialize ($config);
     if (isset ($config['dbconfig']))
     {
       $this->dbconfig = $config['dbconfig'];
     }
  }
```

}

Then, in your controller:

```
class MyController extends AppController
{ 
   public function initialize()
   {
      parent::initialize();
      $this->loadComponent ('My', ['dbconfig' => $this->getDbConfig()]);
   }
}
```

If you really must reference a function and call it, use [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).